# How to extract .pkg extension file data in java

Tags: java

I have .pkg file and I want to extract the data of the file in Java. Whenever I try to extract the data through `ZipFile` it throws an exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\kapilb\Desktop\kapilBaghel\dmserver.pkg (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:214)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:144)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:158)
at dm.com.app.core.database.Testing.unZip(Testing.java:22)
at dm.com.app.core.database.Testing.main(Testing.java:61)
```

The code:

```
public static void unZip(File objZipFile, File objDestDir) {

    try {
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(objZipFile);
        Enumeration<?> enu = zipFile.entries();
        while (enu.hasMoreElements()) {
            ZipEntry zipEntry = (ZipEntry) enu.nextElement();

            String name = zipEntry.getName();

            File file = new File(objDestDir, name);
            if (name.endsWith("/")) {
                file.mkdirs();
                continue;
            }

            File parent = file.getParentFile();
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.mkdirs();
            }

            InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                fos.write(bytes, 0, length);
            }
            is.close();
            fos.close();

        }
        zipFile.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: may be `.pkg` is hidden

Comment: Are you sure you can unzip a .pkg?

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\kapilb\Desktop\kapilBaghel\dmserver.pkg (The system cannot find the file specified)` That's the operating system saying the file doesn't exist. It's very likely that this error message is accurate. Can you confirm that file actually does exist?

Comment: yes i got . Thanks guys                                                             InputStream fin = new FileInputStream("dmproxy.pkg");
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
BZip2CompressorInputStream bzIn = new BZip2CompressorInputStream(in);